# Safe conversion from Unsigned to Signed type

Tags: swift

Having

```
let finalValueUnsigned64:UInt64
```

I would like to convert it to `Int64`

```
let finalValue = Int64(finalValueUnsigned64)
```

But the initializers doesn't throw exception so I can handle the situations, when the value is too large and conversion is not possible. How can I convert any Unsigned to Signed, with some feedback whether conversion is possible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Int64(exactly:)` initializer to check if a value can be converted or not. If the value can't be represented exactly it will return `nil`. For example:

```
Int8(exactly: 100)   // Optional(100)
Int8(exactly: 1_000) // nil
```

Comment: What if the number to be converted is stored in higher resolution type? I have number `65530` stored in `UInt64` and would like to convert it to `Int16`, which should be `-6`. However, `Int16(exactly:)` is returning `nil`.

Comment: In that case you'd use `Int16(bitPattern:)` instead.